# Telegraf Regex expression to fetch last string

Tags: regex, telegraf, telegraf-plugins

As per my requirement I want to fetch last few characters in a string.
For example my string is "hello/how/are/you", here I want only "are/you".

```
[[processors.regex]]
  order = 1305
  namepass = ["*_promitor_test"]
  # Tag and field conversions defined in a separate sub-tables
  [[processors.regex.tags]]
    ## Tag to change
    key = "resource"
    ## Regular expression to match on a tag value
    pattern = "^(.*)$/are.*"
    ## Matches of the pattern will be replaced with this string.
    replacement = "${0}"
    result_key = "resource_type"
```

But I am not getting expected output i.e. "are/you". Can anybody please help me with this expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that language
but for the regex

```
   #edited the regex
   pattern = "^(.*)(are.*)$"
   #group number starts from 1 not 0 
   replacement = "${2}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
.*(are.*)
```

In your snippet:

```js
[[processors.regex]]
  order = 1305
  namepass = ["*_promitor_test"]
  # Tag and field conversions defined in a separate sub-tables
  [[processors.regex.tags]]
    ## Tag to change
    key = "resource"
    ## Regular expression to match on a tag value
    pattern = ".*(are.*)"
    ## Matches of the pattern will be replaced with this string.
    replacement = "$1"
    result_key = "resource_type"
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/q7hT8N/1/).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    are                      'are'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```